# SQL Server 2008 Failover Cluster on Cluster Shared Volumes?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, cluster-computing

Can anyone think of a reason a SQL Server 2008 failover cluster couldn't use Cluster Shared Volumes for databases and log files?

It seems that using CSVs should reduce failover time and reduce the complexity of the cluster group configurations (the physical drive resources wouldn't need to "failover" anymore).

Answer (score 0):

I think, but am not 100% sure, Microsoft restricts what can be on a CSV.

Of course, you can put the VHD there. That's the whole point. And the VHD could contain the database data and log files -- who knows what's "inside" a VHD.

But, not knowing your configuration, I don't know what you are trying to do. CSV is there so a single volume (e.g., a single LUN on a SAN) can be shared by multiple cluster members with individual files there in being used by different cluster members. Specifically, the information making up a VM definition and VHD.

Previously, one had to put the VM definition and VHD in a separate LUN so it could move about individually. There was nothing "wrong" with this other than the complexity of having so many LUNs.

Database files are different. You don't have as many. They are big. You want to carefully place them and watch them. Etc.

If you just put the database files inside a VHD then, as said originally, all is easy, except you don't get the detailed treatment you probably want.

If you put the database files in a separate LUN then you have all of the detailed treatment and that LUN will failover as easily as anything...

Comment: hmm - my understanding of a CSV is more that it is just a magical new sort of storage resource that doesn't need to be failed over.  Certainly, you can always do the traditional failing over of physical disks that are used by SQL Server - but I'm just curious as to if you *need* to do that.

Comment: Actually CSV is just the normal failover file share service for clusters with a behind the scenes wrinkle. You MUST enable the Microsoft Client and Service for SMB on the NIC(s). That puts in place the "one thing manages files, but it can failover to other cluster members". Behind the scenes, the cluster members conspire to give one member (not the one doing the SMB) at a time the rights to read/write the data in the files. It is a limited cluster file system built out of exist pieces with a little conspiracy added. But, it gets the job done.